# List Externals which point to a specific folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, external

i have a question about SVN externals.
So i know that it is possible to check for externals in a specific folder using:

```
svn propget svn:externals
```

or e.g. i can list all external paths by right-click --> Tortoise Svn --> properties.

Is it the other way around also possible ?
e.g. Can i somehow list or see if an external which is located in a diffrent folder points to a specific folder which i want to check ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To see all externals in a project you can do:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R
```

Note that this does not list externals in externals. It only recursively lists all externals in your repository.